# Split string by two or more consecutive whitespaces but not by single

Tags: ruby, string, split

I have

```
str = "this     is    simpl e    string 98"
```

I need something like this

```
["this","is","simple","string","98"]
```

I did this:

```
str.split(" ")
# => ["this","is","simpl","e","string","98"]
```

Comment: What if there was an additional space before `98`? What it was `98bottles_of_beer`? What if `this` were `this7`? Please edit to explain in words what you want. That is, what are the rules? Perhaps give more examples. You need to fix this even though you've selected an answer, as many others will read this question in future. Also, you'll accumulate more downvotes and votes to close until you clarify.

Comment: according to my case `string`  with one space is neglected and `numeric` with single space is taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gsub` function to remove a single space which exists between two alphabets and then do splitting in-order to get your desired output.

```
> str = "this     is    simpl e    string 98"
> str.gsub(/(?<=[[:alpha:]])\s(?=[[:alpha:]])/,"").split()
=> ["this", "is", "simple", "string", "98"]
```